# access to child elements

Tags: angular, angular5, viewchild

I think the only way to do this is a service, but I would like to know if any other way is possible.

Parent:

```
<h1> Parent title </h1>
<child-element></childElement>
```

Child:

```
<form #f="ngForm">
    <mat-card-content>
      <mat-input-container>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="id" name="id" placeholder="ID"  #input/>
      </mat-input-container>
      <mat-input-container>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" placeholder="NAME"  #input/>
      </mat-input-container>
    </mat-card-content>
</form>
```

From child I can access with @ViewChildren:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChildren('input') inputs;
   //rest of code
}
```

but it is possible access all of them in anyway from parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so clear, but if I get it :

```
<h1> Parent title </h1>
<child-element #child></childElement>
```

In your parent TS :

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;

doSomething() {
  console.log(this.child.inputs);
}
```

This allows the parent to have access to the child as a Javascript object. Is this what you wanted ?

Comment: perfect, exactly what I need